# How to validate a text box based on radio button selection in ASP.NET MVC 3 and JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a radio button with values, "Yes" and "No". If user selects "Yes", the text box slides down. So it has to be validated. If user clicks "No", the textbox slides up and there is no need for validation.

I tried to use, ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextBoxValue), but I am not able to submit the form as, it validates the text box even it is slided up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "JQuery.Validate" library might be a reasonable solution. It will allow you to validate your field based on some condition. Syntax is fairly expressive:

```
$("#SomeFormId form").validate({
                rules: {
                    "YourTextBoxId": {
                        required:  {
                            depends: function(element) {
                                return $("#YourCheckBoxId").is(":checked");
                            }
                        }
                    }

// Writing this is notepad, you'll have to look up the syntax if you choose this approach.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field that keeps track of the textbox showing or not. Check the field before validating.

You can even use javascript to see if the textbox.style.display == 'hidden' and run the validate function from that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please, with some code. It will be really helpful.

Comment: If you can post some of your code, I can help you easier too. Assuming your validation function is also in javascript, you can run 2 javascript functions before doing a server side call. Something like onclick="function1(); function2();" function2 will not run if function1 returns false. So in function1, check if your textbox is displaying by: textbox.style.visibility or textbox.style.display. If it is visible, validate in function2. Hope this is more clear now. I'd also appreciate a vote up if it is helpful. Please post more code so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using jquery to slide the `textbox` up and down. Another method would be to toggle the `disabled` attribute of the `textbox` with jQuery when you slide it up or down. Disabled elements don't submit to the server.

edit:
I'd say right after or right before the code for sliding the `textbox` out, you'd do something like the following

```
<<when showing the textbox
$("#textbox-id").attr('disabled', false);

<<when hiding the textbox
$("#textbox-id").attr('disabled', true);
```

This disables the user from using that `textbox` in any way, including submitting it to the server, so the server won't see any values which might be in it.

edit2: Just remembered you'll also need to check the value of the `checkbox` when the form is submitted. If it's checked, check the `textbox`, if it isn't then don't.

Comment: I am new to JQuery. I know only the slideup and slidedown function in JQuery UI. Can u post some link or code to see how the "disabled" works?

Comment: I've edited my response with some code. You'd have to change the textbox-id part though to whatever your `textbox`'s id is. This would go inline with whatever other code is getting executed when the `textbox` is sliding in or out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to check the state of a Radio Button, accordingly show/hide a textbox. When shown it has to be validated, when hidden, no validation required.

I would suggest enabling validation at the rendering time. Now based on selection, you show/hide textbox, ill put the following code inside $(document).ready()

```
    // select the radio button
    var radioBtn = $('#radioBtn1');
    var initialState = radioBtn.is(':checked');

    // hide/show
    var textbox = $('#txtBox1')[initialState ? 'show' : 'hide']();

   // Show/hide based on radio button selection
   radioBtn.click(function () {
        textbox[initialState ? 'show' : 'hide']();
   });
}
```

Hope this helps,
Regards